# Trying to pass image to database in react JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to pass image to mongodb like below.

```js
const [imgfile, setFile] = useState();
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");


    const saveFile = (e) => {
        console.log(typeof( e.target.files[0]));
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        setFileName(e.target.files[0].name);
        
        //formData.append("myImage",e.target.files[0]);
        //formData.append("fileName", e.target.files[0].name);
      };
 
      const uploadFile = async (e) => {
        var formData=new FormData();
        formData.append("file",imgfile);
        formData.append("fileName", fileName);
        console.log(formData);
        try {
          const res = await axios.post(
            "/setting",
            formData
          );
          console.log(res);
        } catch (ex) {
          console.log(ex);
        }
      };


        return (
        <div className="center">
            <section>
                <h1>setting</h1>
                <br />
                
                <input type="file" name="myImage" onChange={saveFile}  />
                <button onClick={uploadFile}>Upload</button>
        </div>);
```

I don't know why the formData would become "{}" after the formData.append. and It seems that nothing can be passed

Comment: What kind of backend do you have ? Express? Are you using multer as middleware ? You need to set the filename like this in order for multer to read it properly: 
` formData.append("file",imgfile, "uploaded-file");`
And you must say to multer to listen for "uploaded-file", then you can change the file name server side.

Comment: Yes I am using Express and multer. I think I should have set it. The problem is that I console.log(formData) after appending would output { }
Which is before passing to the server I think

Comment: It shows {} because a FormData instance is not a common POJO, so you can't log it like that. If you want to log formData you need to do something like:
`[...formData.entries()].forEach(el => console.log(el))`

Comment: Oh that surprised me. I didn't know it can't be logged like that. thank u so much
However, after passing to the server side, I tried to log req.file and that showed undefined.

Comment: You need to make sure you give to the file the same name that you specifiy in multer, the name is the third parameter as I specified in my first comment, it must be the same:
`upload.single('uploaded-file')` in multer,  ` formData.append('file',imgfile, 'uploaded-file')`

Comment: Yes, I did follow. Or shouldn't I log req.file in the normal way?

Comment: Try to check this basic working implementation of image upload:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/multer-mixed-form?path=server.js%3A34%3A35